# How could I uncheck a CheckBox in android app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-checkbox

I have an app which has a checkbox when checked it add a movie to the favorite list
I need to remove the movie from the list when unchecking the checkbox.
I am using content provider.
https://github.com/Alyaa87/PopularMoviesStage2

Comment: Paste the part of code where you actually need help. Ain't nobody got time for reading the entire repo :)

Comment: @aliaa, I'll check your repo.

Comment: Hello, @aliaa, I'll fix the issues for your app. is it acceptable?

Comment: Dear aliaa. I'd like to talk via chat more detail with you. I found the some issue in your app.